# If $Z_1, Z_2$ are iid $N(0,1)$, how can we show that $E(e^{tZ_1Z_2}|Z_1) = e^{\frac{1}{2}Z_1^2t^2}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Z_1, Z_2$ be iid $N(0,1)$, I would like to show that for $t$ a dummy variable:

$$
E(e^{tZ_1Z_2}|Z_1) = e^{\frac{1}{2}Z_1^2t^2}
$$

In other words, I'd like to find the conditional moment generating function of $Z_1Z_2$. My approach is very long, which is by writing out the exponential function power series expansion:

\begin{align}
E(e^{tZ_1Z_2}|Z_1) &= 1+ tZ_1E(Z_2|Z_1) + \frac{t^2Z_1^2E(Z_2^2|Z_1)}{2!}+ \ldots \\
&= 1 + \frac{t^2Z_1^2}{2!} + \frac{3t^4Z_1^4}{4!} + \frac{15t^6Z_1^6}{6!}+ \ldots \\
&= 1 + \frac{t^2Z_1^2}{2} + \frac{\left(\frac{t^2Z_1^2}{2}\right)^2}{2!} + \ldots \\
&= e^{\frac{1}{2}Z_1^2t^2}
\end{align}

Is there an easier way to do this without resorting to pesky power series expansions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M_{Z_2}(t)$ is the MGF of $Z_1$, then you immediately have $$E[e^{tZ_1 Z_2} \mid Z_1] = M_{Z_2}(Z_1 t) = e^{Z_1^2 t^2/2}.$$
Conditioning on $Z_1$ allows you to "treat it as a constant."

Comment: Thanks! I have a quick follow up question, if I wanted to find the expectation of the last result, $E[e^{Z_1^2 t^2/2}]$, is there an easy way to do this too without resorting to integrals or power series?

Comment: @user321627 $Z_1^2$ is a chi-squared random variable, so you could use the MGF of that (which would be derived simply by computing the integral directly).

Comment: @Thanks that's awesome!!